# Should I be commenting that I've flagged a question?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

I've been using Stack Overflow actively only in answering, editing, and commenting on questions, without ever actually asking one, so my frame of reference is slightly limited as far as what feedback I'd expect to receive if one of my own questions were flagged.

Usually I'll leave a comment if the post can be saved, but never tell the inquirer that I've flagged their question.

Is this the correct way of going about this?  Should I ever inform the Inquirer that I've flagged their question?

Comment: It's up to you, but you aren't required to and it rarely seems to be taken positively.

Comment: Anything like that including a simple down vote should require a comment. Not communicating a perceived problem does nothing to resolve the problem or prevent it from re-occurring with that user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you wouldn't comment to say that you've flagged a question.

The purpose of flagging is to bring attention to an issue that you are unable to deal with and someone else is. Assuming that you're truly unable to solve the issue yourself there are two possible outcomes from flagging:

1. Some action is taken
2. No action is taken

In the event that some action is taken then the questioner will be informed about it. The question might be edited, closed or whatever - there will be a result that the questioner can see. Your comment wasn't required.

If no action is taken then nothing happens. Your comment wasn't required.

Now, if you comment you'll either get into an argument or you won't -
we're assuming you definitely couldn't do anything remember. If you do get into an argument you can't do anything about it apart from stop commenting. If you don't get into an argument then nothing has happened again.

There's no real, obvious, benefit to flagging and then commenting about it. If you want to comment then asking directed questions to help the OP improve their post seems like a better strategy.

Comment: Agreed on not showing them immediately, but you could require an explanation and only show it after some action is taken. One of the big long standing problems with this site is that people aren't required to justify their down votes, and even flags are sometimes incorrect.